# Telerik Free Testing Framework vs Selenium

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, telerik, gui-testing

I am choosing one of the following to test with: **Telerik Free Testing Framework** and **Selenium**

The web-project, is a site written in C # and JavaScript.

Can you please tell which of the testers to choose and why?
Highlighting the differences of the above tools for testing?

Comment: @AnthonySottile You really need to say why you caution against it.  Rumors without basis are what -- useless?  Opinions without reasons are surely equivalent to rumors aren't they?

Comment: I recommend listening to a recent podcast where Jesse Liberty interviews Jim Holms, who is the evangelist for Telerik's TestStudio. He is obviously biased in favor of Telerik, but he speaks highly of Selenium and talks about some of the differences between various testing frameworks. He says for some people, it may be a better solution for them to use a solution like Selenium. http://jesseliberty.com/2012/07/05/yet-another-podcast-70jim-holmes-automated-testing/

Comment: We use selenium to test a python based stack and find that selenium flakes nearly all of our tests.  The cross browser automated testing is great, but when it is just so unreliable it is unpleasant.  I'm not sure there is a better way to do it and _some_ testing is CERTAINLY better than none.  It just seems we spend a considerable amount of time inspecting flakes when they are just that -- flakes.  Though perhaps that says something about our code and not necessarily about selenium.

Comment: Check out Cypress, it's way better that Telerik, Selenium, Ranorex, Tosca or any of the others. Tests run fast and reliably, and it's easy to lean. Only downsides are a lack of iframe support and it's Chrome only at this stage. Not that I would recommend cross-browser automated testing anyway...

Answer (score 9):

Full disclosure: I'm the Evangelist for Telerik's Test Studio and Testing Framework, so I've got some biases here.

WebDriver's awesome. I still do lots of workshops and talks around it. Telerik's Testing Framework (free, with a paid support option) has a great story around cross-browser compatibility, implicit and explicit waits, and a few other areas too. It's also a natural progression from that to the full commercial version of Test Studio -- however, you expressly do NOT have to go to the paid tooling if you don't want to.

Either tool will get the job done. The more important aspects of your long-term success with test automation are how you go about the work. Focus on using the Page Object Pattern well (regardless of which framework you use), and learn how to deal with synchronization around dynamic content (AJAX, e.g.). Get those two concepts nailed and you'll be a lot happier whether you're using WebDriver or Telerik's Testing Framework.

Comment: It would be useful to see a feature / capability matrix comparing Selenium with Telerik's offering.

Comment: @CyberMonk http://www.telerik.com/campaigns/teststudio/aw/5-hidden-selenium-costs

Comment: updated link https://www.telerik.com/blogs/five-hidden-costs-of-selenium and link to the PDF that is linked but 404'd.... really Telerik you can do better with updating links https://www.telerik.com/docs/default-source/test-studio/software-testing-costs-whitepaper-teststudio-vs-selenium

Answer (score 3):

I would go with Selenium. I say this for one main thing: open source.

I cannot begin to explain in words, how annoying it was to be calling something from Selenium and it was doing something I wasn't expecting or I'd pass in a value and it wasn't doing anything. Documentation can be a little patchy, so whats next? Look at the source code.

I've learnt how Selenium works back to front by looking at the source code. With Telerik's, you obviously cannot do this.

With browser support, they are the same.

Both are well written, well maintained, Telerik's has dedicated support whereas with Selenium you are stuck to Google groups, Google and Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. An interesting feature)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go with Selenium.  I don't know Telerik but I do know that:

> As of early 2012, Simon Stewart of Google (inventor of WebDriver) and
>   David Burns of Mozilla are negotiating with the W3C to make WebDriver
>   an internet standard. As such, Selenium-Webdriver (Selenium 2.0) aims
>   to be the reference implementation of the WebDriver standard in
>   various programming languages. Currently Selenium-WebDriver is fully
>   implemented and supported in Python, Ruby, Java, and C#.

Of course nobody knows if it will become a standard but the fact that is under consideration gives me hope that what I learn using it will be useful in the future.  Anyway, it's an aspect worth keeping an eye on.

Also, I could do what I needed by reading their documentation.

Comment: Thank you. With regards to WebDrive - W3C yesterday presented a draft of the standard